# Swift 3 IOS Access Class Method from dynamically created button

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton

i am trying to trigger a method from a code generated button...

I get the error: Value of type:  SBSbarcode picker has no member StartScanning.

How could this button access the above methods?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
class scanViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupManualScanner()
}



func setupManualScanner() {

    // Scandit Barcode Scanner Integration
    // The following method calls illustrate how the Scandit Barcode Scanner can be integrated
    // into your app.

    // Create the scan settings and enabling some symbologies
    let settings = SBSScanSettings.default()

    let symbologies: Set<SBSSymbology> = [.code39, .code128]
    settings.settings(for: .code128).activeSymbolCounts =  [11,15,16,17, 18]
    settings.settings(for: .code39).activeSymbolCounts =  [10, 14]

    for symbology in symbologies
    {
        settings.setSymbology(symbology, enabled: true)
    }

    let guiOptions = SBSGuiStyle.laser

    // Create the barcode picker with the settings just created
    let barcodePicker = SBSBarcodePicker(settings:settings)

    // Add the barcode picker as a child view controller
    addChildViewController(barcodePicker)
    view.addSubview(barcodePicker.view)
    barcodePicker.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    // Set the allowed interface orientations. The value UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll is the
    // default and is only shown here for completeness.
    barcodePicker.allowedInterfaceOrientations = .portrait


    // Set custom options
    barcodePicker.overlayController.setVibrateEnabled(false)
    barcodePicker.overlayController.guiStyle=guiOptions


    let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 100, height: 50))
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    btn.setTitle("Click to scan", for: .normal)
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startManualScan), for: .touchUpInside)

    barcodePicker.view.addSubview(btn)

    // Set the delegate to receive scan event callbacks
    barcodePicker.scanDelegate = self
    barcodePicker.startScanning(inPausedState: true)


}

func startManualScan()
{
    self.barcodePicker.startScanning()
}
```

Comment: is it StartScanning or startScanning ?

Comment: startScanning, which works well in the method above but can not be triggered in the button action

Comment: self.barcodePicker where declared ?

Comment: In the above method... but even changing the button action to:         barcodePicker.startScanning() does not work

Comment: Question is, how to access the objects of the setupManualScanner method from the startManualScan method i guess

Comment: check my answer i have declared object globally .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code :

class scanViewController: UIViewController {

```
 let barcodePicker = SBSBarcodePicker // declare here

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupManualScanner()
}

func setupManualScanner() {

    // Scandit Barcode Scanner Integration
    // The following method calls illustrate how the Scandit Barcode Scanner can be integrated
    // into your app.

    // Create the scan settings and enabling some symbologies
    let settings = SBSScanSettings.default()

    let symbologies: Set<SBSSymbology> = [.code39, .code128]
    settings.settings(for: .code128).activeSymbolCounts =  [11,15,16,17, 18]
    settings.settings(for: .code39).activeSymbolCounts =  [10, 14]

    for symbology in symbologies
    {
        settings.setSymbology(symbology, enabled: true)
    }

    let guiOptions = SBSGuiStyle.laser

    // Create the barcode picker with the settings just created
    barcodePicker = SBSBarcodePicker(settings:settings) // made change here

    //continue your code
}


func startManualScan()
{
    barcodePicker.startScanning()
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks. With adding () -->     let barcodePicker = SBSBarcodePicker() // declare here

Comment: Welcome ..@Bubu